# 504 Gateway Time-out GitLab community edition

Tags: nginx, gitlab

I am encountering two issues with our GitLab Community Edition installation on a Debian server. When one of our developers tries to push code, they receive an "HTTP 413 curl error." Additionally, attempting to increase the maximum push size through the GitLab administration interface results in a "504 Gateway Time-out nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)" error.

**Details of the Setup:**

Server: Debian with GitLab Community Edition.
Proxy: Nginx version 1.18.0 is used as a reverse proxy.
Initial Issue: HTTP 413 (Payload Too Large) error on code push.
Secondary Issue: 504 Gateway Timeout when adjusting settings in GitLab admin area.

1. Attempted to increase the push size limit via the GitLab admin interface – led to a 504 error.
2. Modified the gitlab.rb configuration file to increase the size limit, but this did not resolve the HTTP 413 error.
3. Checked Nginx configuration for any relevant settings that might be limiting request size or causing timeouts.